# Where does Phonegap finds the sdk.dir?

Tags: android, cordova, ant

I've installed

- Android SDK
- Apache Ant
- Phonegap (via node.js)
- (all in Windows 7)

Unfortunately I had an old version from the Android SDK & Apache Ant on my PC. Now I have the problem everytime I run

```
phonegap run myProjectName
```

it says this

```
...
Buildfile: D:\Dev\Apps\testApp\platforms\android\build.xml
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource emma_ant.properties. 
            It could not be found.

-set-mode-check:
-set-debug-files:
-check-env:
  [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.0
  [checkenv] Installed at D:\Software\ADT\sdk

BUILD FAILED
D:\Software\ADT\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:483: The SDK Build Tools revision (17.0.0)is too low for project 'HelloWorld'. Minimum required is 19.1.0
```

In my new installation of the Android SDK the folder is now

```
D:\Dev\ADT  // --> not D:\Software\ADT
```

I changed the windows ENVIROMENTS: PATH, ANT_HOME, ANDROID_HOME.
But Phonegap always says that the SDK is installed in that old folder.

What else have I to change here? I can't find it.
Phonegap seems to read some configuration I haven't found yet. Because the problem occurs while run Phonegap. I deleted Phonegap and installed it again but that doesn't fix the problem. So I guess somewhere in windows has to be a config that hold this SDK.DIR with the old values.

Comment: you can try to check you registry using regedit, if there are some pointers referencing your old SDK

Comment: Thx, but I couldn't find the failure. So I tried to delete everything I found and reinstalled all programs. Now it works. My system is running since more then 3 years, so I guess in the next time I had to reinstall my OS to clean all orphaned files.

Comment: Why don't you a Virtual Machine(VM)? That way you do not have do clean up you main system everytime. Just delete the VM and use a New VM when required.

Comment: Hm, ok interesting idea. Never thought about that and this is so easy. :-)

Answer (score 0):

for me it worked when i opened the android sdk manager and updated Android SDK build-tools